# double time data is getting inserted in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

every time i try to insert data my get inserted twice or thrice in the database, the second time instead of data, value 0 is getting inserted.
i too need to insert the data using submit button.but it's not working.

hello_con.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Hello_con extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -  
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //$this->load->view('heloo_view');
    }

    public function heloo()
    {

        $this->load->view('heloo_view');
        $user=$this->input->post('user');

        $user = array(
                'user_name'=>$user
                );

         $this->load->model("heloo_model");
         $this->heloo_model->insert_user($user);
         return $user;
         echo "hi, welcome:"."$user";
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

heloo_model.php

```
<?php
class Heloo_model extends CI_Model {


    public function insert_user($user)
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->insert("userdetail",$user);

    }

}
?>
```

heloo_view.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>heloo world</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>welcome to heloo world</p>

<form method="post">
Enter your name:
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter your name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="sub">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to validate the user as it will be inserting a row, even when you haven't submitted the form.

Comment: remove name attribute from submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as:

```
public function heloo()
{
    if(isset($this->input->post('user'))){
        $user = $this->input->post('user');

        $insert = array(
            'user_name'=>$user
        );

        $this->load->model("heloo_model");
        $this->heloo_model->insert_user($insert);
        echo "hi, welcome:".$user; 
    }

    $this->load->view('heloo_view');
}
```

**Issues in your code:**

1. You are getting empty rows in database because you are not validate the data, you need to validate the either getting from post or not.
2. You are echoing **"hi, welcome"** after using `return`, it cant be return user name because of `return`.
3. Always load your view file at the end of function not on top.

Answer (score 2):

You need to validate the user as it will be inserting a row, even when you haven't submitted the form.

Replace your heloo() with this:

```
public function heloo()
{
    // User will be false if there wasn't any post data
    $user=$this->input->post('user');

    if($user !== false) {
        // The form was submitted
        $user = array(
            'user_name'=>$user
        );

        $this->load->model("heloo_model");
        $this->heloo_model->insert_user($user);

        echo "hi, welcome:"."$user";
    } else {
        // The form needs to be shown here
        $this->load->view('heloo_view');
    }
}
```

This code will show the form initially, until the user submits the form and creates the row.